# Customising MUI Timeline component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

In my react project, for styling I use makeStyles and i'm wondering how I can use that to customise the Material UI Timeline component? More specifically, the TimelineConnector. I thought the styling would be similar to the StepperConnector component but I haven't been able to change anything except for the colour.

I'm trying to have a similar look to the attached photo. Thick lines and no gaps between the dots and the dots and connectors. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It's always recommended to provide some code and show what you have tried, rather than ask people to start from scratch and do it all for you. You want override the `margin` of `TimelineDot` and the `width` of `TimelineConnector`

Comment: Apologies, i'll edit in what I tried so other people can see. Thank you, that did the trick.